# Detecting HTTP client used with HTTP Server?

Tags: delphi, http, indy

I used the same request with 2 differents client HTTP. One is accepted by server (java request in IE) and not the other (Indy Client in Delphi software) ? Is there a way to detect the request difference between the two request ?

Is there a way to hide I use Indy ?

Best regards

Comment: Although it's *possible* that the server is recognizing the difference in clients, it's more likely that you're simply not sending the right request in your Delphi code. As Ernelli suggested, use Wireshark to record exactly what each client sends, and then look for differences that could be relevant besides the User-Agent header.

Comment: It's was working with many servers and still work with many except one (the more used :()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally use TidTCPClient and made my POST request by hand and it works now (it's a long time allready).

I still not understand why but I have no time to look after this.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend Fiddler2, which inserts itself as a proxy, and will record all http/https traffic, with nice inspectors.
http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp

Comment: I want to listen http request on port 2000. Where to change this ?

Comment: +1 - Fiddler is the way to go, you can also modify the request on the fly which should allow you to test if it's just the user agent string that's causing it!

Answer (score 2):

UserAgent is under the Request property.  By default, Indy's user agent string is "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)".  Change it to a current string used by FireFox, IE or other recognized browser.

You can find examples on the [UserAgentString](http://www.useragentstring.com/) site.

There are more details in the [Indy KB PDF](http://www.indyproject.org/KB/Downloads%5CIndyKB.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You must be talking about User-Agent. I'm not sure how you set it in Indy but the User-Agent HTTP header identifies which client is used, so you can set it to pretend you're IE or another browser.

Also, try using an HTTP sniffer (Scoop is a good one on OSX) to see exactly what headers are being sent to make sure you behave exactly like the browser.

Comment: Note that the `user-agent` header is fully controllable by the client. Keep in mind that it can be spoofed.

Comment: The User-Agent is specified in the TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent property.

Answer (score 1):

[wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)/tcpdump is your friend in most situations when there is a need to analyse http requests.

With tcpdump you can record the request on the server, and then analyse the captured data in wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are best of with Paros.
http://www.parosproxy.org/

It will allow you to monitor, pause and customize the HTTP request on-the-fly. It's a hacker tool, but you'll love it.

Answer (score 1):

[**Don's Proxy**](http://donsproxy.moneybender.com/) is a nice free tool to capture HTTP requests. As you write that you are using Java, I assume that the JRE required for this tool is installed already.

Then compare the two requests using [**TortoiseMerge**](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html) or some other diff utility.